# Meteor how to debug allow/deny

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm working on my meteor project and started setting up one of my first more complex allow/deny rules. I find it quite hard to see which allow triggered and which not and what some variables inside these functions contain.
For example:

```
List.allow({
   update: function(userId, docs, fields, modifier) {
       if(!docs.user){
           console.log("list without owner => updateable for everyone");
           return true;
       }
       else if(userId === docs.user){
           console.log("user is owner of list => updateable!");
           return true;
       }
       else {
           console.log("no access, is not owner");
           return false;
       }
   }
});
```

The console.log statements do not work (nothing is logged in the console).
I'd like to know what docs, fields and modifier contains in the moment the allow-rule is checked to adjust my code.
How can I debug in these methods?
If not, can somebody correct my code?
I have a Collection where Meteor.users can have his own record, this should only be updat

Comment: ... able for him. I also have records which belong to visitors without an account. All these should be updatable for "everyone" (if he has the _id).

Answer (score 1):

Use `meteor debug` instead of `meteor run` to start your meteor application. It will add the node inspector package to your running Meteor app so that you can debug it.

Also you can use `Meteor Shell` in the CLI.

For More info [Josh Owen's blog](http://joshowens.me/easily-debugging-meteor-js/)